# .rar file produced while converting java to jar

Tags: java

I am a newbie to the Java Platform. I have been using a book and learning java for a week. Now I wanted to test how to convert java file jar file. When I use the command below, I just get a rar file as output Even the rar file doesn't have a jar file. Please help me.

Command : jar -cfvm HelloWorld.jar MANIFEST.MF MyApp.class

Output : added manifest
adding: MyApp.class(in = 420) (out= 289)(deflated 31%)

System info:
Windows x64 pc

Java SE 16 .zip format

My Code:

```
    class MyApp
{
    public static void main(String args[ ])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Please help me regarding how to generate a jar file and not a rar file

Comment: Just use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse (Eclipse will be easier for exporting as jar file, but IntelliJ is better for programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you say it's a .rar file? Because it has the WinRar icon or is opened by a zip/rar packing/extracting app?

A .jar file is just a basic .zip file (with the class files, optionally the source files, maybe some additional jar and resource files, and the MANIFEST.)

So what happened is either:

1. Your Windows zip/unzip (WinRar, 7zip etc) app added the .jar filename extension to be registered/opened with it
2. Your Linux system (which analyzes the first bytes of a file) recognized it as a .zip file type (that it actually is)

**Solutions:**

- So please check again and make SURE that what you're claiming is actually true. Set your system to show file(name) extensions!
- use the command line to run the jar file: `java -jar filename.jar`
- - if there still is a problem, this will show you more details
- If you're on MS Windows:
- - install a JRE so that it registers the .jar file extension to be run with the JVM
- - or "open with" -> and select the JRE/JVM
- If you're on Linux:
- - set permissions to execute
- - - right-click on file -> permissions -> x
- - - or via command: `chmod ug+x filename.jar`

Comment: You are my saviour!! The reason was jar was assigned to be opened by WinRAR! Thank you Jay!!

Comment: @PraneshSK you might want to accept this answer since it solved your problem.